# Missing last group after aggregation

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an issue with missing some messages after aggregation. I need to aggregate my messages into groups with same number of elements. For my current problem I have 118 elements in `messageChannel`. These messages succesfully combines into 11 groups with 10 elements for each group. But last 8 have been lost

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(messageChannel)
                .split(s -> s
                        .applySequence(false).get().getT2().setDelimiters("[\r\n]"))
                .aggregate(s -> s
                                .correlationExpression("payload")
                                .releaseExpression("size() >= 10")
                                .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                )
                .handle(h ->
                        System.out.println(h))

                .get();
```

I expect receiving 8 lost messages into new group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `expireGroupsUponTimeout` can help here:

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(messageChannel)
            .split(s -> s
                    .applySequence(false).get().getT2().setDelimiters("[\r\n]"))
            .aggregate(s -> s
                            .correlationExpression("payload")
                            .releaseExpression("size() >= 10")
                            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                            .expireGroupsUponTimeout( 500 )
            )
            .handle(h ->
                    System.out.println(h))

            .get();
```

Comment: That's correct. The `groupTimeout` has been introduced exactly for missed this use-case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#agg-and-group-to